# Ошибка «mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/tmp/#sql_3946_0.MAD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space...», как решить?

Tags: apache, nginx, mariadb, centos7

Лог такой:(/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log)

```
180831 18:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Disk is full writing '/var/tmp/#sql_3946_0.MAD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after freeing disk space)
180831 18:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 18:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Disk is full writing './mysql-bin.001289' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after freeing disk space)
180831 18:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:00:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:00:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:10:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:10:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:20:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:20:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:30:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:30:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:40:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:40:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 19:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:00:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:00:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:09:58 [Warning] IP address '*' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180831 20:10:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:10:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:20:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:20:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:30:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:30:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:40:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:40:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:43:58 [Warning] IP address '*' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180831 20:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 20:50:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
180831 21:00:50 [Warning] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Mess180903  8:38:24  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180903  8:38:27  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3369227524552
180903  8:38:27 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Как исправить данную ошибку, я понимаю, что диск переполнен... И что в данных случаях обычно делают?

UPD

```
    df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1        190G  133G   48G  74% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  8.6M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0

# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16359292k,nr_inodes=4089823,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/md1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=24,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1492)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3273980k,mode=700)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

/var/log/messages/ в момент проблемы 31.08 в 18:50, когда упал сервер.

```
Aug 31 18:50:55 it auditd[605]: Audit daemon has no space left on logging partition
Aug 31 18:50:55 it auditd[605]: Audit daemon is suspending logging due to no space left on logging partition.
Aug 31 18:51:01 it systemd: Started Session 61649 of user root.
Aug 31 18:51:01 it systemd: Starting Session 61649 of user root.
Aug 31 18:51:15 it pg_ctl: could not write to log file: No space left on device

Aug 31 19:33:38 it chronyd[700]: Could not write to temporary driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift.tmp
Aug 31 19:40:10 it named[2015]: client ip#42813 (com): query (cache) 'com/ANY/IN' denied
Aug 31 20:33:57 it chronyd[700]: Could not write to temporary driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift.tmp
Aug 31 21:34:28 it chronyd[700]: Could not write to temporary driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift.tmp
Sep  1 00:00:23 it pg_ctl: could not write to log file: No space left on device




    df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md1       12599296 697263 11902033    6% /
devtmpfs        4089823    437  4089386    1% /dev
tmpfs           4092471      1  4092470    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4092471    587  4091884    1% /run
tmpfs           4092471     16  4092455    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           4092471      1  4092470    1% /run/user/0


df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md1          13M  681K   12M    6% /
devtmpfs         4.0M   437  3.9M    1% /dev
tmpfs            4.0M     1  4.0M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            4.0M   587  4.0M    1% /run
tmpfs            4.0M    16  4.0M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            4.0M     1  4.0M    1% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Обычно du -sh /var ,а дальше по обстоятельствам.

Comment: @de_frag,
`у меня эта пака занимает 130GB [root@it mariadb]#  du -csh /var
130G    /var
130G    total
[root@it mariadb]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1        190G  132G   49G  74% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  8.6M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0`
и свободно 49G.

по пути /var/www - 44 G(где сайт есть), и 86 GB- /var/lib 
Что в данном случае делают? Подскажите, пож-ста.

Comment: Сложно понять, что тут в одну строчку написано. Добавьте в вопрос вывод `df -h` и `mount`.

Comment: @de_frag, обновила

Comment: Т.е. на диске "как бы" 48Гб свободно, но в этот момент Mysql  говорит `Disk is full writing`, так? Какие-нибудь еще сервисы ругаются на полный диск? В `/var/log/messages` есть какие-нибудь записи на эту тему?

Comment: @RabIn дык а Вы `df -h` смотрите в момент проблемы, или когда `mysqld` уже вырубилась? Надо в момент проблемы. И ещё посмотрите кол-во инод: `df -ih` (так же в момент проблемы)

Comment: @de_frag 
 я обновила вопрос... 
 в момент проблемы посмотреть не могу.

Comment: Ок. Это было 31-го числа. А сейчас какое состояние у системы? Все также не хватает места для записи?  `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` и `/var/log/messages` содержат такие же сообщения `No space left on device`?

Comment: Мне думается, в это время у Вас что-то заняло все 48G свободного места в корне. Что именно? Я могу лишь гадать. Предлагаю: 1. Как-то расширить свободное место; 2. Перенести БД mysql (и, судя, по `pg_ctl: could not write to log file` у Вас там ещё докучи и postgres есть?) на отдельный раздел

Comment: @de_frag, cейчас таких логов, все решилось ребутом....